# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined, with bootstrap-star-rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this:
https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating

Everything works fine, but I do get this error message in the Chrome Console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined

It appears in star-rating.js line 76, which is the second line of:

```
getPosition: function (e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    return pageX - this.$rating.offset().left;
},
```

Further error info:

```
Rating.getPosition @ star-rating.js:76
Rating.setTouch @ star-rating.js:160
(anonymous function) @ star-rating.js:177
m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
```

I made a fiddle of it which has the exact same issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/dpnrgdk3/

Comment: I dont get that error using Ubuntu Chrome latest

Comment: @M.Doye I am on Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit). Should be latest I think. Did you look in the Chrome console (F12) for the error message?

Comment: The error appears each time you press the rating stars. My Chrome is indeed latest stable release as of 22 october.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in bootstrap-star-rating which I reported and is now taken care of. Updating to current version solved it.